# drop down list had zero value

Tags: asp.net

I had ddl which in selected changed it execute some code 
but when i tried to do that it wasn't worked well  WHEN i checked the reason i found that ddl in selected value =0 also i made all well and this is my code

```
protected void DDlProductFamily_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DDlProductFamily.DataValueField.Contains("ProductCategory_Id"))
            using (SqlConnection Con = Connection.GetConnection())
    {
        SqlCommand Com = new SqlCommand("GetListViewByProductCategory", Con);
        Com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Com.Parameters.Add(Parameter.NewInt("@ProductCategory_Id", DDlProductFamily.SelectedValue.ToString()));
        SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(Com);
        DA.Fill(dt);
        DataList1.DataSource = dt;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a problem then? You did not state any issues or ask any question.

Comment: problem was ddl hadn't value and didn't execute code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SelectedIndexChanged event fires on postback/callback. If you want it to fire when you actually select an item from a DropDownList, make sure you have AutoPostBack="true". For example:

<asp:DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDlProductFamily_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="**true**" ...

If you don't want it to fire when you select an item, then you must cause a postback (by clicking a button, etc...) after changing the selected item and it should fire.

Comment: the problem here 
protected void DDlProductFamily_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["Category_Id"] != null)
        {
            DDlProductFamily.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Filter WithProduct Category--", "0"));
        }
        if (Request.QueryString["ProductCategory_Id"] != null)
        {
            DDlProductFamily.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Filter WithProduct Family--", "0"));
        }
    }